# Display a form from the main form on startup

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to display a small form when the program is ran. This is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 0;
    InitForm init = new InitForm();
    init.Show();
    init.BringToFront();
    comm = init.Start();
    this.Opacity = 100;
}
```

The `Start()` method draws some lines to the list box on the `InitForm`.

I have two problems:

1. When the program starts, the list box is not populated, I just get
   the waiting cursor, then the main form is displayed and the box is
   populated at the same time;
2. The `InitForm` is behind the main form. How do I bring it to front?

Comment: Do you have an infinite thread running on the second form that would be locking it?

Comment: Nope, it's just a sequence of instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see a ListBox in that code.  But painting doesn't happen until the UI thread goes idle again, after your Load event handler completes.  Which also means that the Opacity assignment doesn't accomplish anything.

The Z-order problem is (partly) caused by this too, the main form isn't visible yet so BringToFront() doesn't work.  Use either Show(this) so that InitForm is an owned window that always displays in front on the main form (recommended) or use the Shown event instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
When the program starts, the list box is not populated, I just get the
 waiting cursor, then the main form is displayed and the box is populated
 at the same time;
```

What do you expect should happen? Your UI Thread is busy in executing the code below

```
this.Opacity = 0;
InitForm init = new InitForm();
init.Show();
init.BringToFront();
comm = init.Start();
this.Opacity = 100;
```

Once it gets freed it shows both the forms and list box populated. It is behaving correctly in my opinion

`this.Opacity = 0;`
Above line won't have any effect because UI thread will execute all the lines first then it will display the UI which means by the time UI shows something `this.Opacity = 100;` would have already been executed

```
    I want to display a small form when the program is ran. The InitForm 
is behind the main form. How do I bring it to front?
```

Why don't you set the `Small Form` as startup form and load the `MainForm` in load method of small form?

Answer (score 0):

You should load the secondary form on a paralell thread.
So, on the Form1's load event handler you trigger the second thread, showing the Form2.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring the Init form to front by setting this property

```
init.TopMost=true
```

It worked for me, check out,